# How to prepare french fries?

Tags: baking, french-fries, cooking-myth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make McDonald’s type French Fries](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8473/how-can-i-make-mcdonalds-type-french-fries)

I have prepared french fries couple of times in my home. But I couldn't get the same kind of spongy fries as I had in Mc donalds. I want to prepare a delicious spongy french fries.
In some blogs I read that we have to put cut potatoes in cold water before frying. But that too doesn't work.  Help me

Comment: I would google a bit to know who manufactures the fries for McDonalds in your area. Where I live they are manufactured by McCain, and [here they tell how are made](http://www.mcdonalds.es/calidad/procesos-calidad/patata).

Answer (score 6):

French fries are often double-fried:

1. They are par-fried at a low temperature, to cook all the way through, after which they are often frozen
2. They are finish-fried at a higher temperature to crisp up and be hot for presentation

The type of potato matters--high starch like Idahos are ideal.

Here is a link to a [Serious Eats article](http://aht.seriouseats.com/archives/2010/05/the-burger-lab-how-to-make-perfect-mcdonalds-style-french-fries.html) by Kenji Alt describing his preferred technique in exquisite detail.

His technique actually involves par-boiling, then par-frying, then (for optimal results, he says) freezing, then finally finish frying.   The interesting thing is that freezing actually has an affect on the outcome--it isn't just for storage and transport.

Comment: See also http://web.archive.org/web/20110630182837/http://www.cookingissues.com/2010/04/27/the-quest-for-french-fry-supremacy-part-1/ and http://web.archive.org/web/20100916081938/http://www.cookingissues.com/2010/05/12/the-quest-for-french-fry-supremacy-2-blanching-armageddon/

Answer (score 1):

McDonalds (and other companies) fries are shot through a screen using a water cannon and go straight into hot oil where they are fried, before being frozen. They are then shipped frozen to the stores where they are then fried in oil again before being served, so they are twice-fried.

More than the method of frying though is the variety or potato you use. If you use "wet" potatoes then you won't get good fries no matter how you prepare them, you want one with a medium to high starch content. In the US that means russet potatoes, in the UK that means Maris Pipers or King Edwards.

Comment: According to Kenji's article, McDonalds actually blanches their fries in water before the par-fry.   Who knew?

Comment: Not surprising as the potatoes they use have to high a starch content. A par-boil would help break down the carbs into sugars, which would make them taste sweeter and help make a more crunchy outside.